# UPDATE query that fixes orphaned records

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, sql-update, orphan

I have an Access database that has two tables that are related by PK/FK. Unfortunately, the database tables have allowed for duplicate/redundant records and has made the database a bit screwy. I am trying to figure out a SQL statement that will fix the problem.

To better explain the problem and goal, I have created example tables to use as reference:
[alt text http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/9243/514201074110am.png](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/9243/514201074110am.png)
You'll notice there are two tables, a Student table and a TestScore table where StudentID is the PK/FK.

The Student table contains duplicate records for students John, Sally, Tommy, and Suzy. In other words the John's with StudentID's 1 and 5 are the same person, Sally 2 and 6 are the same person, and so on.

The TestScore table relates test scores with a student.

Ignoring how/why the Student table allowed duplicates, etc - The goal I'm trying to accomplish is to update the TestScore table so that it replaces the StudentID's that have been disabled with the corresponding enabled StudentID. So, all StudentID's = 1 (John) will be updated to 5; all StudentID's = 2 (Sally) will be updated to 6, and so on. Here's the resultant TestScore table that I'm shooting for (Notice there is no longer any reference to the disabled StudentID's 1-4):
[alt text http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/1954/514201091121am.png](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/1954/514201091121am.png)
Can you think of a query (compatible with MS Access's JET Engine) that can accomplish this goal? Or, maybe, you can offer some tips/perspectives that will point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to post table structures? How are you identifying the duplicates, is it a manual process or is there another table containing ONLY duplicates, or are you just using students with the same name and hoping there aren't just two people who actually share a name?

Comment: Yes, I posted the structures in a image ref. Apparently, you don't see the images - Here are the direct links to the images of my sample table structures:
http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/9243/514201074110am.png
http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/1954/514201091121am.png

In my example, I'm just identifying dupes by the Name field. But in my actual database it is by a product serial number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is through a series of queries and temporary tables.

First, I would create the following Make Table query that you would use to create a mapping of the bad StudentID to correct StudentID.

```
Select S1.StudentId As NewStudentId, S2.StudentId As OldStudentId 
Into zzStudentMap
From Student As S1
    Inner Join Student As S2
        On S2.Name = S1.Name
Where S1.Disabled = False
    And S2.StudentId <> S1.StudentId
    And S2.Disabled = True
```

Next, you would use that temporary table to update the TestScore table with the correct StudentID.

```
Update TestScore
    Inner Join zzStudentMap
        On zzStudentMap.OldStudentId = TestScore.StudentId
Set StudentId = zzStudentMap.NewStudentId
```

Comment: I didn't think to use a temp table. Thanks, Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

The most common technique to identify duplicates in a table is to group by the fields that represent duplicate records:

```
ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
1   Brian   Smith
3   George  Smith
25  Brian   Smith
```

In this case we want to remove one of the Brian Smith Records, or in your case, update the ID field so they both have the value of 25 or 1 (completely arbitrary which one to use).

```
SELECT  min(id)
    FROM example
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
```

Using min on ID will return:

```
ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
1   Brian   Smith
3   George  Smith
```

If you use max you would get

```
ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
25  Brian   Smith
3   George  Smith
```

I usually use this technique to delete the duplicates, not update them:

```
DELETE FROM example
      WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT   MAX (ID)
                           FROM example
                       GROUP BY first_name, last_name)
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian. That's a cool method for deleting duplicates.

However, although I'd be fine with deleting duplicates from my sample Student table, it is mandatory that I save (Update) the existing records in the TestScore table.

Referring back to the sample TestScore table, you'll notice that there are records for John(ID=1) and John(ID=5). The problem is, John ID1 and ID5 are the same person. So, I want to update all the ID=1 to ID=5.

I do not want to lose track of the history for all of John's (and the other students') test scores.